# Socket Programming when there is a path

Tags: python

For python

so if you do socket programming u would do a host and port e.g. localhost and 9999 respectively

what if instead of port u have a path e.g. localhost/foo

could u still program a server and client connection without a port number and a path instead e.g. localhost/foo

if not, then would http library work instead so like at the top instead of import socket u type import http and use the thing http library has instead of socket library

is there a way to do it with socket in python when u have a path like localhost/foo but no port i.e. u do not have a host and port like localhost and 9999

Comment: AFAIK, you're always connecting to some port, and it doesn't make sense to "connect" when there's no port to connect to. There's no port in `http://example.com`, for instance, because it's assumed the port is 80 or 8080, but the port is still there anyway. Also, IMO, paths are a feature of the _protocol_, which can be established using any port you like. For example, you can easily run an HTTP server on port 1234 or whatever

Comment: Socket programming deals with TCP layer, where host and port are mandatory parameters of the connection. Path belongs to the HTTP layer. Whenever HTTP port is omitted in a URL, port 80 is assumed, so `http://localhost/foo` means that you're connecting to `localhost:80` and then send the HTTP request with the path `/foo`.

Comment: Berkeley socket interface concepts stem from back in the days of manually moving cables to connect various phone lines so people could talk to each other. "Not having a port" would be like your house's landline phone not being plugged in anywhere on the operator's switchboard.

Comment: When you go to `http://localhost:9999/foo`, browser sends `GET /foo HTTP/1.1` (with headers after it) as socket request and than gets reply

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this picture (found [here](https://microchip-mplab-harmony.github.io/net/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=01429.html)):

[image]

Network protocols form a stack where the protocols above rely on the protocols below. For example, when you write a regular letter to your friend, all you care about is to write it in a proper language and write a correct address on the envelope. All the logistics details, whether your letter is delivered by an airplane or a train, or by pigeons - are none of your business, they belong to the lower-level protocol. The post service, in turn, doesn't care about the content of your letter, it just needs to deliver it in time.

A similar thing happens with networking. As you can see on the diagram, HTTP belongs to the highest, Application layer. HTTP services use notions like "URL" or "header", or "content type", but the underlying TCP protocol only cares about delivering the data from one host to another. So, terms like "host" and "port" are from TCP, and terms like "path" are from HTTP.

When you send an HTTP request, for example `http://hostname/foo`, your host establishes the TCP connection using the host and port information (`hostname` and `80` is the default port), and then sends the HTTP request over that connection, and that's where path `/foo` is taken into use.

Now, socket API operates on the transport layer, so it doesn't know anything about paths. You *can* use socket API to send an HTTP queries, but:

- you need to know quite well how HTTP works
- it's a lot of manual work
- any existing HTTP library uses sockets under the hood

To summarize, you don't really need to deal with sockets for HTTP. Python has modules [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) and [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#module-http.client), but the most popular and easy-to-use Python library for that purpose is [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). With it, sending a request is as simple as:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://localhost/foo')
```

Comment: Just to confirm: import http is usable and import socket is unusable in this situation?

Comment: @premiumtopstrong I see now that my explanation was confusing, I updated it, hope that helps.